# Split cell into rows, but with respect to data in original row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel table that starts off looking like this:

| Project | Company | Authors | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | Company A | Mr. A. Brown, Ms. C. Dalek, Mr. D. Echo | 09/09/2009 |
| B234 | Compaby B | Ms. B. Crayon | 01/01/1970 |
| C567 | Компания C | мистер Джон Доу , мс джейн доу | 02/03/2003 |

Using text to columns I can get to this:

| Project | Company | Author 1 | Author 2 | Anuthor 3 | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | Company A | Mr. A. Brown | Ms. C. Dalek | Mr. D. Echo | 09/09/2009 |
| B234 | Company B | Ms. B. Crayon |  |  | 01/01/1970 |
| C567 | Компания C | мистер Джон Доу | мс джейн доу |  | 02/03/2003 |

I'd like to transform the table so it looks more like this:

| Project | Company | Author | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | Company A | Mr. A. Brown | 09/09/2009 |
| A123 | Company A | Ms. C. Dalek | 09/09/2009 |
| A123 | Company A | Mr. D. Echo | 09/09/2009 |
| B234 | Company B | Ms. B. Crayon | 01/01/1970 |
| C567 | Компания C | мистер Джон Доу | 02/03/2003 |
| C567 | Компания C | мс джейн доу | 02/03/2003 |

Closest I've gotten is using pivot tables, but it ends up nesting the rows which I don't want. Plus there's a lot of empty cells. The list is in multiple languages, which hopefully isn't too much an issue but I thought worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use PowerQuery for such things:

[image]

- Select your data in `A1:D4`, or if you have a table like in the image above, just click any cell in the table;
- Then click From Table/Range from the Get & Transform Data section of the Data ribbon (confirm you have headers if it asks for);
- PowerQuery will open. Select the "Authors" column;

[image]

- On the "Home" tab, click "Split Column" and choose to split by delimiter;
- On the opened pane, choose to split by comma and go to "Advanced Options" where you will choose to split to rows.
- Click OK and close PowerQuery (save your progress if it asks you);

[image]

---

Here is the M-code if one want to:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project", type text}, {"Company", type text}, {"Authors", type text}, {"Start Date", type datetime}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Authors", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Authors"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Authors", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Answer (score 2):

1] In `H2`, formula copied down :

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&TEXTJOIN(",",,C$2:C$4),",",REPT(" ",99)),ROW(A1)*99,99))
```

2] In `F2`, formula copied right to `G2` & `I2` and all copied down :

```
=IF($H2="","",LOOKUP(1,-SEARCH($H2,$C$2:$C$4),A$2:A$4))
```

[image]